# Force UIImagePickerController to Crop a Square Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

How do we force UIIImagePickerController to crop a square image?

I have searched all over and I haven't found a solid solution.  Thankyo

```
var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController();
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;



func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    profilePictureSelected = true;

    profilePictureImageView.image = image;

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

Comment: you can't force it, you have to resize it after you get the image from the delegate call back, there's a lot of methods out there that show you how to resize the image to a square crop by cutting the larger of width or height

Comment: Not sure what Objective-C has to do with this. Please fix your tags.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are doing it correctly up until you receive your delegate callback, within the callback you need to specify that it's the edited image that you want to use. Please note that i'm using a different delegate method here.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

        profilePictureSelected = true;

        profilePictureImageView.image = chosenImage;
    }
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Swinny89  . This was truly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 4**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
       viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
           if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage {
               yourUIImageView.image = image
           }
       })
}
```